# How to know describe the set of levels for functions f(x,y)=c when c varies

Tags: calculus, functions

Hey im having quite troubles trying to understand how to describes the set of levels in functions. In [this](http://puu.sh/q703J/95d262578f.png) problem any ideas?

$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1$, then your level sets would be $c=x^2+y^2+1$, or, rearranging terms, $x^2 + y^2 = c-1$, which correspond to a circumference centered in $(0,0)$ and with radius $r = \sqrt{c-1}$ on the $x,y$ plane.

For $c=1$, you will have a dot as level set, while for $c>1$ you will have circumferences. That particular function $f(x,y)$ actually represents an elliptic [paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid).

Comment: ty for the help.